# how to pass the current group as argument in a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group' : ['a','a','a','b','b'],
                   'value' : [1,2,3,10,20]})

Out[39]: 
  group  value
0     a      1
1     a      2
2     a      3
3     b     10
4     b     20
```

Essentially I would like to group by `group` and be able to call a `function` that uses the value of the current group (`a` or `b` in this example) as an argument. That is, my function takes as input the current `value` and its corresponding `group`.

Something like

```
def myfunc(mygroup, myvalue):
    return myvalue.astype(str) + mygroup

df.groupby('group').value.apply(lambda x: myfunc(mygroup,x))
```

Which does not work.
Expected output is:

```
Out[38]: 
0     1a
1     2a
2     3a
3    10b
4    20b
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: df.value.astype(str) +df.group , it can do the same task seems, do you want to have in different way

Comment: yes, that must happen in a `groupby`. the original problem is more complex, as I need to load an external file which depends on the current group

Comment: I still did not get why need name in the groupby ?

Comment: The expected output didn't show urgency of using groupby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try grouping the dataframe and adding the specific columns in groupby function

```
df.groupby(['group']).apply(lambda x: x['value'].astype(str) + x['group'])
```

Out:

```
group   
a      0     1a
       1     2a
       2     3a
b      3    10b
       4    20b
dtype: object
```

**or**

you can also try of looping the groups individually and adding the group to value

```
pd.concat([g['value'].astype(str)+i for i,g in df.groupby(['group'])])
```

Out:

```
0     1a
1     2a
2     3a
3    10b
4    20b
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:x['value'].astype(str)+ x['group'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any `group` function when you already have a group column use:

```
df['value'].astype(str)+df['group']

0     1a
1     2a
2     3a
3    10b
4    20b
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting an exact output as you desired, by modifying your code:

```
def myfunc(mydf):
    return mydf.value.astype(str)+mydf.group

df.groupby('group').apply(myfunc).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Additional note, might answer your curiosity.

**SeriesGroupBy**

Doing `df.groupby('group').value` will result an object of `SeriesGroupBy` of column `value` that has been grouped by column `group`, so that when you called `.apply` in your code, it expected Series (column `value`) as an argument to your function.

```
df.groupby('group').value.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str)+group))
# x is Series of column 'value'. This will raise error, since 'group' isn't recognized`

df.groupby('group').value.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str)+df.group))
# use dataframe 'df' to access column 'group'
```

**DataFrameGroupBy**

At the other hand, doing `df.groupby('group')` will result an object of `DataFrameGroupBy`, so that calling `.apply` will expect a Dataframe as an argument to your function. Hence, you can access to all columns e.g:

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.value.astype(str)+x.group)
# here x is a dataframe, it can access all columns.
```