# Groupby group as argument to groupby apply to speed up

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe `a`

```
    Dim1  Dim2  Dim3  Dim4  id
0      1     2     7    15   1
1      1    10    12     2   1
2      9    19    18    16   1
3      4     2     4    15   1
4      8     1     9     5   1
5     14    18     3     2   1
6     19    19    19    17   1
7     14    18     3     2   1
8     85    16    35    61   2
9     71    13     7     4   2
10    74     1     2    81   2
11    50    25    19    85   2
12    74     1    37    31   2
13    21    57    51    13   2
14    25    80    51    47   2
15    91    34    30    75   2
16    34    77    10    76   2
17    84    98    25    33   2
18    82    69    24    44   2
19    88    44    74    31   2
```

to which I am trying to apply a function `f` to every `id` group and to every row. I wrote it like this

```
def f(row, df):
    
    group = row["id"]
    df = df.query("id == @group")
    # keep only columns we need
    
    
    #filter for all rows where none of the columns are worse
    df = df[(row <= df).all(axis = 1)]
    #filter for rows where any column is better.
    df = df[(row < df).any(axis = 1)]
    
    count = len(df)
    return count
```

It works when I do `a.apply(f, args = [a], axis = 1)`. The result is

```
0     2
1     2
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     1
6     0
7     1
8     0
9     5
10    0
11    0
12    1
13    1
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    0
19    0
dtype: int64
```

However, I think there is probably a way to edit my function so that I do not do repetitive filtering as you see below, apply that function row-wise to `a.groupby("id")`:

```
def f(row, df):
    
    group = row["id"]
    df = df.query("id == @group")
    ...
```

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52574363/how-to-pass-the-current-group-as-argument-in-a-groupby), however did not find the answer I am looking for. How I can I add `groupby` object itself to a function and also do it row-wise?

Comment: What is your expected output from this dataset?

Comment: I added the output

Answer (score 1):

Let's try cross merge on `id` and query:

```
features = df.columns[:-1]

(df.assign(counter=df.index)
   .merge(df, on='id')
   .query(' and '.join([f'{col}_x<={col}_y' for col in features]))
   .query(' or '.join([f'{col}_x<{col}_y' for col in features]))
   .groupby('counter')['id']
   .count()
   .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
0     2
1     2
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     1
6     0
7     1
8     0
9     5
10    0
11    0
12    1
13    1
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    0
19    0
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

---

**Update**: per your comment:

```
features = df.columns[:-1]

def myfunc(d):
    a = d[features].values
    diff = a[:,None,:] - a
    out = (diff<=0).all(-1) & (diff<0).any(-1)
    return pd.Series(out.sum(-1), index=d.index)

df.groupby('id').apply(myfunc)
```

Output (note that level 1 index is the index of the original dataframe):

```
id    
1   0     2
    1     2
    2     1
    3     2
    4     2
    5     1
    6     0
    7     1
2   8     0
    9     5
    10    0
    11    0
    12    1
    13    1
    14    0
    15    0
    16    0
    17    0
    18    0
    19    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you!. Yes, it works, yet I am specifically looking for a way to convert the solution to `a.groupby.apply` type. Because I have many functions like that and I am unable to rewrite each of them. I will upvote your answer of course

Comment: @EmilMirzayev sure, see update. Generally, when you have to compare each row to all the rows in the same group, we either think of cross-merge or groupby.